# select1 onChange doesn't change select2 value

Tags: reactjs

I have two select with two different values and options. I would like to set the second value undefined and refresh the selected value in the select field. If I see console.log(selected2), it's undefined so the selected value changes correctly but on the screen the page always shows the previously selected value.

```
const [selected1, setSelected1] = useState();
const [selected2, setSelected2] = useState(value2);

const onChangeValue1 = (value) => {
  setSelected1(value);
  setSelected2(undefined);
}
```

Comment: to un-set a `select` element, set its value to an empty string, not `undefined`.